# pickling functions and multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am confused with this...Since python cannot pickle functions, hence preventing us from passing a wrapper function to `Pool().map()` then how come this works?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64844943/5431734

Comment: It is using multithreading (`from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool`), not multiprocessing (`from multiprocessing.pool import Pool`). The code could have also more simply done `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`.